# String assignment to dataview unexpectedly removes data row

Tags: vb.net

I'm stumped on a problem where VB is removing a row of data upon a simple string assignment.  The processing loop is below. If the `dvData` dataview has 3 rows (i.e., `dvData.Count` is 3) then the string assignment below is causing the dataview to lose a row (i.e,. after executing the string assignment the `dvData.Count` is 2).  What more odd is that this same string assignment call is used many other times in the same script without causing the loss of a data row.

```
For Each oneShipment As Shipment In DelShipmentsList
    For intRow = 0 To (dvData.Count - 1)

        ' Example: if dvData.Count is 3 at this point, then....
        dvData(intRow)("Result") = "     Receipt Transaction Accepted."
        ' ... now dvData.Count will be 2!

    Next
Next
```

Comment: Obviously, the posted code won't reproduce that behavior.

Comment: Did you Try/Catch to see if it errors?

Comment: Hi DonA, thanks for the reply.  Yes, it was wrapped in a Try/Catch, with no exception thrown.  Also, that snippet is used all over the same script with no problems.  As odd as the bug may seem, I've documented the source of the problem in the answer I just posted. It's an odd one for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try examining your RowFilter property for that DataView object.  If it's something like this, it would explain the issue:

```
dvData.RowFilter = "Result NOT LIKE '*Accepted*'"
```

Comment: Bingo. I checked and indeed there's filter set very close to what you have there. I don't know why we missed this the first time. Thanks for the fast response!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we found the answer, albeit completely unforeseen and worthy of much head scratching.  Just to be super sure about passing integers and strings explicitly, I had him us CStr() and CInt() where appropriate.  Here's what we found:

```
' This string causes the dataview to change error
dvData(CInt(intRow))(CStr("Result")) = CStr("Receipt Transaction Accepted")

'This string does not.
dvData(CInt(intRow))(CStr("Result")) = CStr("Receipt Transaction Successful")
```

Apparently there’s something about the word "accepted". We spent quite a while trying different strings to figure out why the Specified string causes the odd behavior that remains otherwise unexplained.